# Anyone using Source-Connect?

Tags: remote

I have had a couple of requests for remote monitoring and or remote recording here at the studio.  I do not have ISDN or really much experience with that.  I was curious is anyone has use Source-Connect and could shed some light on it.

http://source-elements.com/

I want to demo it, but without another studio to connect to and do some experimenting with it would be tricky to test out the demo.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using SC pretty much since it came out. Like any new technology it has it's up side and it's down side. Much like ISDN, it is NOT an install and go type of thing. You do need to have some IT saavy to get it working to peak efficiency- or you can pay Source Elements to help you set it up. If you have a fairly stable internet connection and are willing to spend some time learning it, then you can get excellent results. Both EdNet and Digiphone offer ISDN to SC bridging so you can connect to ISDN studios as well.

The one down side of SC is that unlike ISDN, you are at the mercy of the IP pathway between you and the other studio. If there's a server along the line that's causing a problem, then the session can quickly sink with lost connections and audio glitches. It's not a common problem, but it can happen and there's very little that can be done. Also SC to SC connections seem to be fraught with more peril, as lots of studios have it installed, but many don't know how to set it up and use it. The only problem I've ever had with a ISDN to SC Bridge was when the receiving ends ISDN box blew up! :)

So, in a nutshell, if you are willing to spend the time with it (which you would with ISDN as well), and are willing to deal with the fact that many ISDN studios which tried it back in it's early days have written it off as unusable, and have a solid internet connection, then you can get excellent results. ISDN is of course proven, and reasonably reliable, but much more expensive, and frankly, almost impossible to get installed new these days.

Comment: this pretty much sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Source Connect has loop back sites, termed "Echo", that allow you to perform tests.  You can do the testing with the demo version as well.

ISDN is much more reliable.  When I use it, I always have the talent side run a back-up recording available via FTP.  It is very useful for quality distance monitoring of sessions.